# How to get the transfer function for the diagram?

Tags: circuit-analysis, current, transfer-function

I want to obtain the transfer function for the current through the first resistor (i1)as i1(s)/vi(s). Could you help me with that?

[image]

Comment: The diagram in the question looks the same as that in [Is the transfer function for the given RC network right?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/438104/is-the-transfer-function-for-the-given-rc-network-right), which already has an accepted answer.

Comment: Yes, the same, but that get Vo(s)/vi(s)

Comment: You are looking for the input admittance. Does that help you?

Comment: Yes, well, I mean the current that R1 has, but in transfer function I1(s)/Vi(s). "